# Monte Carlo approximation of call option on the maximum of two assets

Tags: programming, monte-carlo, exotics

I want to compute the price of the option with payoff
\begin{equation}
\max \big\{\max\{S^1_T, S^2_T\} - K, 0\big\},
\end{equation}
where $S^{1,2}$ have the same dynamics with 0 correlation. So,
\begin{align}
dS^1_t &= r S_t^1 dt + \sigma S^1_t dW^1_t \\
dS^2_t &= r S_t^2 dt + \sigma S^2_t dW^2_t,
\end{align}
where $W^1$ and $W^2$ are independent Wiener processes under the pricing measure $Q$. This option has analytical pricing formula (e.g. in [The Complete Guide to Option Pricing Formulas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071389970), p.211). However, when I try to compute the value of this option using MC method, I get values that are consistently incorrect.

Below is my code for the MC simulation. First a function to do the numerical integration of the SDEs:

```
# Euler scheme for two GBMs (no correlation) with same drift and volatility
# Returns the terminal value (prices at last time step)
gbm <- function(mu, sigma, max_time, num_steps, init_value){
  h = max_time / num_steps
  paths <- matrix(NA, num_steps+1, 2)
  paths[1, ] = init_value
  normals = matrix(rnorm(num_steps*2, sd=sqrt(h)), num_steps, 2)
  
  for (i in 1:num_steps){
    paths[i+1, ] = paths[i, ] + (mu * paths[i, ] * h) + (sigma * paths[i, ] * normals[i, ])
  }
  return(paths[num_steps, ])
}
```

Then the Monte Carlo method. Note that I compute the price for a call option on the maximum AND the price for just a vanilla call:

```
trials <- 10000
maxes <- array(NA, trials)
max_payoffs <- array(NA, trials)
vanilla_payoffs <- array(NA, trials)

for(i in 1:trials){
  # Compute terminal values of the SDEs
  terminal_values <- gbm(mu=0.02, sigma=0.2, max_time=3, num_steps=1000, init_value=c(1, 1))
  # Vanilla call payoff just on one of the GBM - for assuring my numerical integration correct
  vanilla_payoffs[i] <- max(terminal_values[1] - 1, 0)
  
  # Call on the maximum of the two assets - strike 1
  maxes[i] = max(terminal_values)
  max_payoffs[i] = max(maxes[i] - 1, 0)
}

# Mean of the payoffs + 95% confidence interval
mean(max_payoffs) * exp(-0.02 * 3)
sd(max_payoffs * exp(-0.02 * 3)) * 2 / sqrt(trials) 

# Mean of the vanilla call payoffs
mean(vanilla_payoffs) * exp(-0.02 * 3)
```

For the call on the max of two assets, my sample mean is $0.2839 \pm 0.0064$ which is very far off the correct value of $0.2235$. However my vanilla call option is almost exactly right $0.1656$ compared to the true value $0.1646$.

Just to be clear, the parameters are $\sigma=0.2$, $r=0.02$, $S^{1,2}_0 = 1$, $K=1$, $T=3$, $\rho=0$.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could explain where I am going wrong.

EDIT:
I added python code which uses no numerical integration as per @Yoda And Friends's answer. It still gives incorrect price though:

```
def terminal_spots(trials, r, sigma, t, spot):
    normals = np.random.normal(size = (trials, 2))
    return spot * np.exp(t * (r - 0.5 * sigma * sigma) + sigma * np.sqrt(t) * normals)
```

and

```
def mc_call_max_two_assets(trials, r, sigma, t, spot, strike):
    terminals = terminal_spots(trials, r, sigma, t, spot)
    max_terminal = terminals.max(1)
    payoffs = np.maximum(max_terminal - strike, 0)
    mn = payoffs.mean() * np.exp(-r*t)
    conf_interval = (payoffs * np.exp(-r*t)).std() * 2 / np.sqrt(trials)
    return mn, conf_interval
```

Comment: Are dynamics without $dt$? Or is it a typo?

Comment: @YodaAndFriends Sorry, yes it was a typo, edited now

Answer (score 5):

I image you want to calculate the following payoff:
$$\pi_T = \max\left[ \max(S_T^1, S_T^2) - K, 0 \right]$$
If dynamics are expressed with the following dynamic (from your code, it should be the case):
$$dS_t^i = rS_t^idt + \sigma S_t^idW_t^i$$
where $W = (W^1, W^2)$ is two dimensional SBM, then, I guess you could simplify your code a bit!

From your definition of the problem, the contingent claim is path-independent. This means you are only interested in finding $S_T^i$ which is a just a random variable. Let us see if we can find its distribution! Take the following transformation:
$$d(\log(S_t^i)) = (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)dt + \sigma dW_t^i$$
which is just short hand notation for the following integral representation:
$$\log(S_t^i) - \log(S_0^i) = \int_0^t (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)ds + \int_0^t \sigma dW_s^i$$
Being $r$ and $\sigma$ constant, and since $\int_0^t \sigma dW_s^I \sim N(0, \int_0^t \sigma^2) = N(0, \sigma^2 t)$ we have that:
$$\log(S_t^i) \sim N\left(\log(S_0^i) + (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t, \ \ \sigma^2 t\right)$$
We can then "simulate" a standard normal distribution $Z \sim N(0, 1)$ using our laptop:
$$\log(S_t^i) \sim \log(S_0^i) + (r - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t + \sigma \sqrt{t} Z$$
With this in mind: $S_t = \exp(\log(S_t))$. So that our Monte Carlo method boils down to this:

```
def generateStock(initialValue, sigma, rfr, t, randomGenerator):
    z = RandomGenerator.nextGaussian(0, 1)
    return initialValue*Math.exp((rfr - 0.5*sigma*sigma)*t + sigma*Math.sqrt(t)*z)

def monteCarloMaxOption(initialValue, sigma, rfr, strike, maturity, numberOfSimulations):
    sample = [0]*numberOfSimulations #Just create an array of length nos
    for w in range(numberOfSimulations){
        stock1 = generateStock(initialValue, sigma, rfr, maturity)
        stock2 = generateStock(initialValue, sigma, rfr, maturity)
        maximumStock = Math.max(stock1, stock2)
        sample[w] = Math.max(maximumStock - strike, 0.0)
    }
    discountFactor = Math.exp(-rfr*maturity)
    priceToday = mean(sample)*discountFactor
    sampleError = errorFunction(sample)
    return priceToday, error
```

I am sorry to have used pseudo code (Python style with Java influences... :D) but I find R really difficult!

If the payoff is not what you intended, please let me know!!!

Comment: Thanks so much! No problem with the pseudo code. Can you look at my edits to the question? I followed your approach (in Python), which gives answer consistent with my R code. However, it still does not match the true price? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I actually tried myself with a tested library I have built. I get that the option value is 0.285188 with an error of 9.5E-4. Are you completely sure the theoretical one is 0.22? If so, are the parameters you provided here correct?

Comment: Yes you're right, that was the mistake. (I had set $b_1=b_2=0$ in the pricing formula). Thanks a lot for your time explaining the answers and writing the code :)

Comment: No worries! I actually had fun!!! :D

Answer (score 4):

### I believe something is wrong with your analytical pricing formula:

**I have provided an R script for the analytical pricing formula specified on (*p. 211*) and it gives a call price of 0.2853.**

```
library(pbivnorm)

maxassets_analytical <- function(r, T, K, sigma1, sigma2, S1, S2, b1, b2, rho){

  y1 <- (log(S1/K) + (b1 + sigma1^2/2)*T)/ (sigma1*sqrt(T))

  y2 <- (log(S2/K) + (b2 + sigma2^2/2)*T)/ (sigma2*sqrt(T))

  sig <- sqrt(sigma1^2 + sigma2^2 - 2 * sigma1 * sigma2 * rho)

  d <- (log(S1/S2) + (b1 - b2 + sig^2/2)*T)/ (sig*sqrt(T))

  rho1 <- (sigma1 - rho * sigma2)/sig

  rho2 <- (sigma2 - rho * sigma1)/sig

  call <- S1 * exp((b1 - r) * T)  * pbivnorm(y1, d, rho1) + 
  S2 * exp((b2 - r) * T)  * pbivnorm(y2, -d + sig * sqrt(T), rho2) - 
  K * exp(-r * T) * (1 - pbivnorm(-y1+sigma1*sqrt(T), -y2 + sigma2 * sqrt(T), rho))

  return(list("call price" = call, "y1" = y1, "y2" = y2))

}
```

Where $b_1$ and $b_2$ is the cost-of-carry for respectively, $S_t^1$ and $S_t^2$. For non-dividend paying stocks the cost of carry equals the risk-free rate. Inserting your specified parameters as-well as $b_1=b_2=0.02$ gives **0.2853**:

[image: results]

**For brevity, I have provided a picture of the formula below**.

[image: maxcallformula]

Here, $M(a,b,\rho)$ is the cumulative bivariate normal distribution function (as seen in *Chapter 13*).

---

#### Verification:

I verified my code by implementing the analytical pricing formula for the corresponding put option, since he provides an example calculation specified on (*p. 212*). **Not only that, but the put option nests the analytical formula for the call option, which gives a way to verify it**:

[image: maxput]

I implemented the put pricing function in `R` and the code can be found below. Following **his example** and thus inserting the parameters, $S_1=100$, $S_2=105$, $X=98$, $T=0.5$, $r=0.05$, $b_1=-0.01$, $b_2=-0.04$, $\sigma_1 = 0.11$, $\sigma_2=0.16$, $\rho = 0.63$, I get the following results:

[image: results2]

**Which agrees with the result in his example**:

[image: Haugresult]

I hope this helps!

---

#### Code for the Put option:

```
maxassets_analyticalput <- function(r, T, K, sigma1, sigma2, S1, S2, b1, b2, rho){

  sig <- sqrt(sigma1^2 + sigma2^2 - 2 * sigma1 * sigma2 * rho)

  d <- (log(S1/S2) + ((b1 - b2) + (sig^2)/2)*T)/ (sig*sqrt(T))

  cmax0 <- S2 * exp( (b2 - r) * T) + S1 * exp( (b1 - r) * T) * pnorm(d) - S2 * exp((b2 
  - r)*T) * pnorm(d-sig*sqrt(T))

  cmax <- maxassets_analytical(r, T, K, sigma1, sigma2, S1, S2, b1, b2, rho)

  pmax <- K * exp(-r * T) - 
  cmax0 + cmax[[1]]

  return(list("put price" = pmax, "cmax, K = 0" = cmax0, "cmax" = cmax[[1]],
   "d" = d, "sigma" = sig, "y1" = cmax[[2]], "y2" = cmax[[3]]))
}
```

Comment: I was worried the analytic value indicated was not the right one when I tried the problem myself! Thanks for having clarified that!

Comment: This is incredibly helpful @Pleb, thank you! My misunderstanding came from the cost-of-carry rate. I set $b_1 = b_2 = 0$ in the pricing formula (gives a price of 0.22...), I did not realise that it should equal the constant short rate. Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me :)